# How to get a Hostname details which are connected to SQL Server databases

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to find list of users / hostname details which are connected from last one year to a SQL Server database?

Thanks

Comment: I can use Sp_who2 , it is giving only latest connection details

Comment: and what is the goal to get this information ?

Comment: What do you mean "from last one year"? SQL Server doesn't log this information on its own. If you want something like that, you should have set up auditing... at least one year ago.

Comment: You'll need to capture that information (e.g. using DMVs as the source) and save to a user table for historical reporting.

Comment: We are migrating our Db's to new versions, So we just want to know which users/host machines are using our servers

Comment: There's no historical view for this, you have to capture this information yourself in real time - which you could achieve from a logon trigger. Be aware that Microsoft also says this about [HOST_NAME](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/host-name-transact-sql)... *The client application provides the workstation name and can provide inaccurate data. Do not rely upon HOST_NAME as a security feature.*